# Armoury Crate - Asus Laptop

Tags: asus, battery

So I made the grave mistake of buying an Asus laptop to have Ubuntu on.
The laptop comes with an app called Armoury Crate, which is used to change the back light of the keys and OC the CPU/GPU when you are in Windows OS.
on Windows I have my settings set to power saving, so the cpu and gpu don't run hot when I am just web browsing.

But when I switch to Ubuntu (dual boot) my cpu/gpu settings reset back to default factory setting (gaming mode, so they start working overtime) and the laptop gets super hot, and my battery life goes down to 1 hour... (all I am doing in Ubuntu is coding and some web browsing).

Is there any way I can disable this stupid app in Ubuntu?

Also, I called Asus Customer support for help and they said they only support Windows, and will only solve Windows problems...

Edit: i forgot to mention that my laptop has NVIDIA optimus

Answer (score 1):

You can try installing CPUfreq. From Point 4 from [Most Effective Ways To Reduce Laptop Overheating In Linux - It's FOSS](https://itsfoss.com/reduce-overheating-laptops-linux/):

> With CPUfreq, you can choose the mode you want the laptop to run in. There are three modes, performance, on demand and power saver. Running the laptop in Power Saver mode reduces overheating. The tool is easy to use thanks to its [indicator applet in Ubuntu](https://itsfoss.com/7-best-indicator-applets-for-ubuntu-13-10/). To [install CPUfreq in Ubuntu](https://itsfoss.com/cpufreq-ubuntu/) based Linux distributions, use the following command:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install indicator-cpufreq
> ```
>
> When installed, just choose the power saver mode from the indicator applet.
>
> [image]
>
> Last I know, CPUfreq doesn’t conflict with TLP. I think it should not conflict with thermald and Laptop Mode Tools as well (if you install them as well).
>
> Out of the four tools mentioned, which one should go with?? Answer differs from person to person. I usually install TLP along with CPUfreq. But you can try each one of them one by one to see which one works the best for you. It will be easier to see the performance of these tools if you monitor your computer’s temperature. We are going to see next on how to monitor hardware temperature.